# Wpf listbox of images from observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `Window` that has a `ListBox` inside it.
The lisbox itemtemplate ->datatemplate has a border stackpanel with checkbox and image.
The listbox itemssource is an observablecollection of string that represents images link.
The source of the image object inside the template is binded to the relevant link.

The issue is that the listbox shows all of the pictures excepts few depends on the number of pictures in the specific path(`directory.getfiles("*jpg")`)

I can see the object of the listbox created because i see a border and checkbox without image inside it and the path in the collection is correct, Everything is ok with the picture in the directory... Anyone has any idea? 
I tought about memory problem but nothing seems to solve it..

I cant post the code because its on a computer that i cant connect to the internet or any other device so i pictured it but i cant upload images because i've just registered so here you can see links to the images in imageshack:

1. http://imageshack.com/a/img834/1594/f33jh.jpg
2. http://imageshack.com/a/img834/1994/gyu54.jpg
3. http://imageshack.com/a/img842/7894/y4x0d.jpg

Thanks in advance,
Snir.

Comment: Don't describe your code... that's no good to us. *Show* us your code (by editing your question, *not* by adding it in a comment)... but please... *only* the relevant code. Please also show us the file paths of some of your images that didn't display and verify that they *do* actually exist.

Comment: I hope i could bu My code is wrriten in a computer that i cant connect to internet or plug any device to it... So start write everything here is quite annoying... I will if no one will understand... But i hope that this is a simple question...

Comment: This was *not* a request... it is a [requirement of this website](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). At present, your question is off topic because it is a *Question that lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.* As such, I have now voted to close it, but will be happy to retract my close vote once you have provided the *required* information.

Comment: Well that was hard but i hope now its o.k?

Comment: It's too hard to see your code in those images, but I did see some error... you're calling `Directory.GetFiles` in a `BackgroundWorker`, which is pointless because that method takes little time to complete. Even if you have millions of files in your folder, then you should just use the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in your `foreach` loop *on the UI thread*, as you can start iterating the files before the method is complete. So, first things first... get rid of that pointless `BackgroundWorker`. Next, you need to find a way to show actual code in your question, not these dodgy images.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I wanted to use the backgroundworker because it takes a lot of time for the images to show for some reason and the gui gets stuck... I understand that the list of strings is fast i'll get rid from the BW... And update. There was no bw when the problem occured first so thats not the point but i will change it. Any else idea why the gui get stuck and some images cant load? Sorry for the images but thats the best i can do...without I took them from iphone send to mail upload and post...

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img837/7877/99ti.jpg  Here is the code without the bw the xaml change is only adding the lisbox loaded event... Same problem...